# Scala Constructor Inheritance of InheritDoc?

Tags: scala, inheritance, scaladoc

I'm writing some documentation for my exception classes and am running into the following warning from scaladoc:

> The comment for class BarException contains @inheritdoc, but no parent comment is available to inherit from.

After reading [this Java question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402275/javadoc-inheriting-parent-constructors-documentation) I have to imagine that the reason for this is because I want to inherit documentation on the constructor method and not just a normal method:

```
/** Base Exception
 *
 *  @param msg A message describing this exception
 *  @param cause The exception which is the underlying cause to this FooException, null if this is the underlying cause
 */
abstract class FooException(val msg: String, val cause: Throwable) extends RuntimeException(msg, cause)

/** The bar exception specific docs, expect msg & cause to be given same docs as FooException
 *  @inheritdoc
 */
case class BarException(override val msg: String, override val cause: Throwable) extends FooException(msg, cause)
```

[image: Parent Documentation Screenshot]
[image: Child Documentation Screenshot]

I understand that there's no override of the constructor, and so nothing to inherit from for that. But, That said, if I look at the generated documentation for the parent `FooException` I see that not only does the constructor have the arguments documented as expected, but also the fields of `msg` and `cause` are documented too. Which seems to imply to me that scaladoc has taken the `@param` and applied it to my fields for `FooException` in addition to using it as the method param documentation

Since I have to `override` in the case class constructor of `BarException`, I'd expect scaladoc to understand that there is something being overridden and therefore something to inherit documentation from, but this isn't the case. I've looked through the [scala tags wiki](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Tags+and+Annotations) but haven't found anything about this behavior or how to get the documentation to inherit from the properties in the parent class to the children.

If I change the class to use `def` then I can inherit documentation onto the fields of the children, but I have to repeat myself:

```
/** Base Exception
 *
 *  @param msg A message describing this exception
 *  @param cause The exception which is the underlying cause to this FooException, null if this is the underlying cause
 */
abstract class FooException(msg: String, cause: Throwable) extends RuntimeException(msg, cause) {

    /** A message describing this exceptionxx */
    def msg: String

    /** The exception which is the underlying cause to this FooException, null if this is the underlying cause */
    def cause: Throwable
}
```

Is there anyway to not use the `def` format in the abstract class and just inherit the documentation to the child that scaladoc is already producing for the generated properties of the parent class?